# PHP INSERT AND LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with inserting one field from a table to another. I have two tables: member and reservation table. In both table I have **member_ID** I want to get the value of the **member_ID** from **member table** and insert it in reservation table.

This is my code:

```
$type=$_POST['serv_name'];
$no=$_POST['reserv_hours'];
$time=$_POST['reserv_time'];
$date=$_POST['reserv_date'];
$ID=$_POST['member_ID'];
$fn=$_SESSION['fn'];

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (serv_name,reserv_hours,reserv_time,reserv_date,member_ID)
VALUES ('$type','$no','$time','$date',$ID)");

$sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (reserv_ID,serv_name,reserv_hours,reserv_time,reserv_date,member_ID)
(SELECT r.reserv_ID,r.serv_name,r.reserv_hours,r.reserv_time,r.reserv_date,m.member_ID  FROM reservation r LEFT JOIN member  m ON r.member_ID=m.member_ID)");

$result = ($sql.$sql1);
if($result)
{
    header("Location:payment.php");
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR!";
    header("refresh:5;url=main.php");
}
```

It is working and it do register in my database but the **member_ID** in my reservation table remained 0. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to echo your query.

Comment: what is r? You do not define any table to r in your select... Try just the select, no insert and you'll be able to troubleshoot easier.

Comment: How you are relating your member table and reservation table, do you have any other field which is common between both tables?

Comment: Unrelated, but your echo at the end should be placed after the header... Headers won't be able to be sent. Unless you have output buffering, but still best to play along the rules even if.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM reservation r
```

you forgot the alias

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, there are 2 mistakes:

We'll look at the SELECT only.

1. You need to alias your table, you used r.fields but never declared which table is r.
2. You are selecting the the memID from a joined table that is joined by that id... Why fetch it in another table instead of just taking the one you have?

With that said, here's the suggestion:

```
SELECT r.reserv_ID,r.serv_name,r.reserv_hours,r.reserv_time,r.reserv_date,r.member_ID  FROM reservation r
```

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for that simple mistake. >.< I did edit it already. And about the same field in the same table, no. I don't have any other field that is common between the two.

Comment: If you do not need fields from member table, just don't join it for nothing :)

Comment: but i need the member_ID from the member table but I don't have any other common fields between the two. is there any way I can get the member_ID in the member table and put it in reservation table?

Comment: Is there a member_ID column in your reservation table? Looking at your queries, it seems so. You do not need to get it from the member table, just get it from the reservation table!